# Combining array elements into a single one, up to a certain point

Tags: php, arrays, blogs

I'm building a lifestream-esque sort of blog in PHP. It fetches my blog posts from my MySQL database, as well as my tweets and my Last.fm scrobbles.

So far so good, but I'd like to combine multiple subsequent scrobbles into one. Everything needs to remain chronological, though, so if a blog post or a tweet breaks a chain of scrobbles, the second part of the chain must not be combined with the first part.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contents] => Disturbed
            [type] => scrobble
            [published] => 1327695674
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contents] => Amon Amarth
            [type] => scrobble
            [published] => 1327695461
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contents] => Apocalyptica
            [type] => scrobble
            [published] => 1327693094
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [contents] => This is a tweet. Really.
            [type] => tweet
            [published] => 1327692794
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [contents] => Dead by Sunrise
            [type] => scrobble
            [published] => 1327692578
        )
)
```

So since [3] is a tweet, scrobbles [0]-[2] should be combined into one element. The timestamp [published] should be set to the most recent of the combined elements, and the [contents] string will be put together using commas. But [4] cannot be a part of the combination, since that would break the chronological order of things.

If you're still with me: I guess I could use loads of iterations and conditions etc., but I'm not sure about how to handle things with performance in mind. Any array-specific functions I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$posts = array( /* data here: posts, tweets... */ );
$last_k = null;

foreach( $posts as $k => $v )
{
    if( ( null !== $last_k ) && ( $posts[ $last_k ][ 'type' ] == $v[ 'type' ] ) )
    {
        $posts[ $last_k ][ 'contents' ][] = $v[ 'contents' ];
        $posts[ $last_k ][ 'published' ] = max( $posts[ $last_k ][ 'published' ], $v[ 'published' ] );
        unset( $posts[ $k ] );
        continue;
    }
    $posts[ $k ][ 'contents' ] = (array)$v[ 'contents' ];
    $last_k = $k;
}
```

Because 'contents' index is array now you will have to use join function for the output.
Like:

```
foreach( $posts as $v )
{
    echo '<div>', $v[ 'type' ], '</div>';
    echo '<div>', $v[ 'published' ], '</div>';
    echo '<div>', join( '</div><div>', $v[ 'contents' ] ), '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is even more usable, as I can now easily array_unique() it to prevent an artist from showing up multiple times in one entry. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a classic [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
$lastType = "";
$count = 0;

foreach($arrays as $array) {
    switch($array["type"]) {
        case "scrobble":
            if($lastType == "scrobble")
              $count++;
            else {
                $count = 1;
                $lastType = "scrobble";
            }
            break;
        case "tweet":
            // same as above
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

```
$last_type = '';
$out = array();

foreach ($events as $row){
    if ($last_type == 'scrobble' && $row['type'] == 'scrobble'){
        array_pop($out);
    }
    $out[] = $row;
    $last_type = $row['type'];
}
```

Looping over each entry, adding them to an output array. When we encounter a scrobble where the previous entry was also a scrobble, remove the previous entry from the output list.